# How to set a div coming from master file as hidden in some other aspx page?

Tags: html, asp.net, resources, master-pages, hidden

I have check.aspx file which has:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MSW.master" %>
```

And in this master file I have:

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/Common/StatusBar.ascx" TagName="StatusBar" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
```

And in this StatusBar.ascx, I have a div:

```
<div id="status_box_content">
    <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server" Text="Welcome " ></asp:Label>                              
    <asp:Label ID="lbUser" runat="server"meta:resourcekey="lblFullNameResource1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPartnerInfo" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:HyperLink Font-Underline="False" NavigateUrl="~/profile/Logout.aspx"
    ID="HLinkLogout" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="HLinkLogoutResource1">Logout</asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

I want this div with `id ="status_box_content"` to be invisible in check.aspx file. But everything else from master file is needed.

How do I make the div invisible while keeping the master file?

Comment: I found the **solution** to this : In your check.aspx, hide the div using jquery. It works perfectly fine. I was making a huge mistake while calling it.So yeah,it works! :)

Comment: @ShurtiAgrawal ,  Just upload your answer and accept it so that it will be removed from Unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your check.aspx, hide the div using jquery**. It works perfectly fine. I was making a huge mistake while calling it.So yeah,it works! :)

Comment: Add Code block so that may it helps other in future.

Answer (score 0):

Notes: Make your div runat="server"

**Aspx Page**

```
<div id="status_box_content" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" runat="server" Text="Welcome " ></asp:Label>                    <asp:Label ID="lbUser" runat="server"meta:resourcekey="lblFullNameResource1"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="lblPartnerInfo" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
  <asp:HyperLink Font-Underline="False" NavigateUrl="~/profile/Logout.aspx"
    ID="HLinkLogout" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="HLinkLogoutResource1">Logout</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
```

**Code Behind Page : Put This Code in your content page_load event**

```
HtmlGenericControl DivCount = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("status_box_content");
 DivCount.Visible = false;
```

Comment: If I do this I am getting the below mentioned error: 
**"Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls".**

Comment: If I try with the updated answer I get this 
**Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Please provide full code what you have tried. Master page HTML and content page code.

Comment: Try this [http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/102437/error-only-content-controls-are-allowed-directly-i.aspx]

Comment: welcome @shurti .If this works for you then please click up arrow (This answer is useful). This helps other if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Make `runat= server` to your div.

And then on page load of check.aspx use make that div invisible:

```
this.Master.findcontrol("divname").visible= false;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `div` is inside `UserControl` and `User Control` is inside `Master Page`, just try to access `UserControl` First in your page, then find out `div` and make it invisible. You could try out this:
 First make the div as server control,Add `runat="server"` in `div` :

```
<div id="status_box_content" runat="server">

    UserControl uc = ((UserControl)this.Master.FindControl("ucTopUser"));
    HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl )uc.FindControl("status_box_content");
    div.Visible = false;
```